# Get height of child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The below ReactJS code produces the `heroHeight` as `undefined`. However it would work on an element. How can I get the height of a component when imported?

```
class IndexPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      heroHeight: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      heroHeight: this.calcHeight()
    });
  }

  calcHeight() {
    return this.hero.clientHeight;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout heroHeight={this.state.heroHeight}>
        <Hero ref={elem => (this.hero = elem)} />
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default IndexPage;
```

Comment: Try to bind this on calcHeight in constructor or modify calcHeight in arrow function.

Comment: Thanks @VladBîcu. Still producing as undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using: `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`

```
 const height = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.hero).getBoundingClientRect().height
```

its possible to get the parent as well:
const height = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.hero).parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height

functions explained:

findDOMNode - simply a method for getting the element you want to work with

parentElement - The parentElement property returns the parent element of the specified element

getBoundingClientRect - returns an object of the positions of the element’s left, right, top, and bottom border. These properties are independent of any css presets. It is called directly on the html element in the document.

Comment: I have not been able to make this work. Could I ask if you could expand your answer with a snippet that includes my code above. I'm getting the `const` height is undefined. Along with a `eslint` warning to using `findDOMNode`. Cheers

Comment: What I have done is wrapped the `component` in a `div` and set the `ref={elem => (this.hero = elem)}` to the `div`. This produces the height as with my above code but if you have a moment to elaborate on your answer it would be greatly appreciated. My solution brings an unnecessary element of a `div`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: look at the updated code, and try with parent as well

Comment: I have the exact same problem as @Darren His solution with wrapping the component in a `div` worked for me however I agree with him that this is a bit hacky and introduces an unnecessary element. The `findDOMNode` is not recommended as well at this point. So my question is: Whats the reason for the `undefined` height and how to solve it properly?